# Find the matrix A of the linear transformation T(f(t))=f(4) from P2 to P2 with respect to the standard basis for P2, {1,t,t2}.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find the matrix A of the linear transformation T(f(t))=f(4) from P2 to
>   P2 with respect to the standard basis for P2, {1,t,t2}. Note: You
>   should be viewing the transformation as mapping to constant
>   polynomials rather than real numbers, e.g. T(2+t−t2)=−4+0t+0t2.

This is a question from my linear algebra class. I have done some questions similar to this one but I am confused by the T(f(t))=f(4) part.

The answer is a 3 by 3 matrix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that $T$ maps polynomials to polynomials. A polynomial is a special type of function, and as such, we can substitute particular values into the given polynomial. In this case, the map $T$ takes a polynomial function, substitutes $t = 4$ into the polynomial to get a constant, and then turns that constant into the constant function.

For example, to compute $T(2t^2 - 1)$ we substitute $t = 4$ into the polynomial $2t^2 - 1$ to obtain the constant $2(4)^2 - 1 = 31$. So,
$$T(2t^2 - 1) = 0t^2 + 0t + 31.$$

To form the matrix, you need to compute $T(1), T(t),$ and $T(t^2)$, i.e. find the image of the basis under $T$. Then, you need to compute the coordinate column vectors for the resulting polynomials under the given basis.

Let's get you started. If we evaluate $T(1)$, we substitute $t = 4$ into the constant polynomial $1$ to get $1$ (the constant polynomial takes the value of $1$ at any $t$, including $t = 4$). So,
$$T(1) = 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot t + 0 \cdot t^2.$$
Therefore, the coordinate column vector with respect to the basis $(1, t, t^2)$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
This forms the first column of your matrix. Do the same with $t$ and $t^2$, and you'll get the other two columns.